# SMPlayer plays mp4 video too fast on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, video, video-player, mplayer, smplayer

Another way:

I try to download source and compile latest mplayer, Now when I play mp4 file with command line `mplayer Train.mp4` have no problem, but still when play with smplayer have the same problem.

Is there any other way except add `-fps 23.976` to SMPlayer?

mp4 file detail:

[image: video file details]

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem in Xubuntu 14.04. Some videos are being played extremely fast in both mplayer and smplayer.

Thanks for your workaround with ''-fps'' parameter, now I am able to play the weird videos with correct speed via:

```
mplayer -fps `exiftool *.MOV | grep -i "frame rate" | cut -d : -f 2` *.MOV
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to update mplayer to the latest using testing repo.

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mplayer-test
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mplayer`

Another option is to change the FPS, but this will cause issues in HD videos. So, better update mplayer to the latest.